# select TOP n Rows from table where n is in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I achieve this without using Dynamic SqlQuery?

I have this Query,

```
SELECT TOP n FROM mytable WHERE ID = @id
```

To get the value of n,

```
SELECT nCOUNT FROM myAnotherTable WHERE ID = @id
```

Can I use Row_index() for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this....but make sure that your `select ncount` return single row.....if not than it will select top row `ncount`

```
SELECT TOP(SELECT TOP 1 nCOUNT FROM myAnotherTable WHERE ID = @id) * FROM mytable WHERE ID = @id
```

SqlFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75c76/1

Comment: To make sure your attempt does not run into an error when `SELECT nCount...` returns more than one row, limit the output: `SELECT TOP 1 nCount ...`.