# Why this Where condition returns 0 Rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
SELECT
  *
FROM tblName
WHERE mode = '1' AND (category = @Category OR @Category = 'all' OR NewsId = @Category)
```

I passed @Category='all'. This returns 0 rows. If `OR NewsId=@Category` this condition not added, query will return all results

Comment: what about `mode` is it `1` ?

Comment: NewsId doesn't have 'all'. But I don't think that ll make probs

Comment: If either `category` or `NewsId` is `null`, this condition evaluates to `unknown`.  Those rows would be filtered out.

Comment: category=@Category this statement is useless. when you pass @Category='all'

Comment: @Andomar - No it wouldn't evaluate to `unknown`. `(unknown or true or unknown) == true` and the OP says they passed `@Category='all'`.

Comment: Please post the entire code.

Comment: @MartinSmith please refer this link http://pastie.org/7942196

Comment: @SubinJacob - Looks like that should work to me as long as you have rows with `mode = '1'` and `@startposition <= @stopposition` and `@stopposition` is `<=` the number of matching rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
   mode = '1' 
AND 
(
      @Category = 'all' 
    OR 
      @Category IN (category, CAST(NewsId AS VARCHAR(10)))
)
```

Do not use too large data-type length (i mean MAX):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TBL_ContentsPage
(
      NewsId INT IDENTITY(1001,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , Header NVARCHAR(1024) NULL
    , SmallImage IMAGE NULL
    , TextContent NVARCHAR(2048) NULL
    , PostedDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE())
    , mode VARCHAR(50) NULL
    , [status] VARCHAR(50) NULL
    , category VARCHAR(200) NULL
    , author NVARCHAR(1024) NULL
    , imgRefID VARCHAR(50) NULL
)

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPGetArticlePaging]
(
      @startposition INT
    , @stopposition INT
    , @Category VARCHAR(200)
)
AS BEGIN

    SELECT 
          NewsId
        , Header
        , TextContent
        , author
        , PostedDate
        , category
        , imgRefID 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              NewsId
            , Header
            , TextContent
            , author
            , PostedDate
            , category
            , DateRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PostedDate DESC) 
            , imgRefID 
        FROM dbo.TBL_ContentsPage 
        WHERE mode = '1' 
            AND 
            (
                  @Category = 'all' 
                OR 
                  @Category IN (category, CAST(NewsId AS VARCHAR(10)))
            )
    ) t
    WHERE DateRank BETWEEN @startposition AND @stopposition 

    RETURN 0

END
```

Comment: NewsId is `int`. Conversion failed when all passed!.

Comment: Please add DDL with your table structure.

Comment: I have a small wish for your future questions. Please format them by any free SQL formatter, like [On-line SQL Format](http://www.sql-format.com/)

Comment: Thank you! but i'm using regional language in unicode. I couldn't figure out how much the characters will be

Comment: That was a nice tip! Thank you

Comment: @Subin Jacob, I am glad that I was helpful to you :)

Comment: My Server running out of CPU due to the execution of some SP. Please help me to figure this out (out of scope- this question).Urgent .. pLease help

Comment: Hi. Please provide your SP's.

Comment: It was due to the repeated execution of the SP.Exposure to Media made a lot of user hits to our web app. SPs were executed at the time of page rendering and we enabled output cache (asp) for all pages. Do you have any advice to take as precaution ??? Thank You!

Comment: If understand you right, maybe, You need to cache the results of the query on `localStorage` (HTML5) (not in IIS) - it will reduce server load on page reload.

Comment: Don't know whats happening now! The Sql server uses 100% CPU and hangs. Restarting will solve the issue. The site is a CMS and calls an SP to load Each article Content. Query is a simple Select statement (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514838/select-top-n-rows-from-table-where-n-is-in-another-table). While using who_2 this SPID consumes much of the CPU. Don't know how to troubleshoot this situation

Comment: The sqlserver making my complete server down

Comment: Сan be many reasons for this situation. Sorry, but I don't have a crystal ball :(